# Prevent require() for files in a lower directory?

Tags: php

Okay so I have a bit of a plugin system setup but need a little bit of assistance with regards to preventing files within a folder from "require()" or "include()" the files before it. Allow me to make a little picture:

```
plugins
|- pluginOne
|- |- config.php
include
|- classes
|- |- user.php
|- config.php
```

Okay so the config.php in the include directory should have full control over the user.php (class) inside the classes directory. However, I don't want the config.php in the plugins/pluginOne directory to be able to touch the user.php

To further expand, I only want the config.php inside the pluginOne directory to be able to include/require classes inside the same directory as it (or in a directory that's in the same directory as it)

I'm sure it's probably possible for me to do some security by checking the contents of the file and seeing if it contains certain phrases and then flag it up if it does. Although I would like to see if theres a better way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you mean by "full control" or "touch" ... do you mean write access to these files?

Comment: Well user.php is a class, I don't want plugins/pluginOne/config.php to be able to include/require the user.php and then trigger the functions inside. I only want the config.php inside include/ to be able to run the functions inside user.php (in this example) Hope that clarifys it

Comment: I don't think there is any way to do this in PHP.

Comment: I was thinking that, but posted to see if anyone has an idea. Thanks anyway!